# Why do we declare string, number, boolean, void and etc in angular2?

Tags: angular

I am confuse why do programmers declaring class in individual scope or something.

Example

```
result: boolean = false
public generateRand(x): void { }
```

This is also similar to

```
result = false
public generateRand(x) { }
```

** Same with the other declarations.

What's the reason behind those declaration? Is it the proper practice for programming or OOP(not sure of this since I don't have good grasp with it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript - which means that TypeScript is JavaScript + more, where the *more* part is type annotations.

TypeScript has a .ts extension. You can compile TypeScript by running the following command:

```
tsc greeter.ts
```

Type annotations give you type safety. That is, when typescript is compiled the compiler looks at the static types, and ensures that the function or variable contract is valid at the time that the script is compiled.   Otherwise, the compiler complains when the types or contracts are incompatible.

**Example**

```
function greeter(person: string) {
    return "Hello, " + person;
}

var user = "Jane User";

document.body.innerHTML = greeter(user);
```

The function greeter expects a string as a parameter.  This code is synatically valid, and will happily compile with no compile-time errors.

On the other hand, if an incorrect type (such as an array) is passed:

```
function greeter(person: string) {
    return "Hello, " + person;
}

var user = [0, 1, 2];

document.body.innerHTML = greeter(user);
```

An error would be displayed when the script is compiled:

```
greeter.ts(7,26): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target
```

Comment: You explained it excellent but how about void? Now I understand what's the use of some. In short, to prevent error occurring from the compiled script. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The main reason is Static Typing

Javascript is a dynamically typed language. That is, the type of a variable is inferred at runtime. This can cause trouble to developers if they put a wrong type in a variable (Example: Putting a String where a Number should be)

TypeScript avoids these mistakes by defining the type of a variable in the code. So any attempts to put a different kind of value (Example, String in a Number) will result in an error. It also helps code completion because it knows what kind of value is being returned.

But these types exist only in the source. In the compiled JS, there is no trace of them.

Cheers!

Comment: It's important to note that most of the transpilers that convert TypeScript back to JavaScript treat the _"errors"_ as _"warnings"_. This can result in undesired behavior as the operation ultimately completes successfully but runtime errors may occur.

Comment: @War10ck that's true but the compilers notify you that what you are doing is almost certainly going to fail

Comment: That's correct. Your answer is by no means wrong. Just a little heads up to watch out for the subtle warnings. My Visual Studio build routine transpiles my TypeScript but I have the _"Warnings"_ window pinned and hidden. This has caused me some grief in the past and so now I keep it open when transpiling. Just wanted to share in case someone else goes through this scenario.

Comment: Thank you so much. Appreciated your effort.

Comment: @HermLuna avoid writing "thank you" comments, instead, select an answer as accepted. it's good stackexchange etiquette :)

Answer (score 2):

You are right. You should not declare type in that particular example, as the type is already acknowledged via [Type Inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html)

However, you will need to consider declaring type to variables with no initial value AND you explicitly want those variables to store a certain type of value:

```
isActive: boolean;
errorMessage: string;
```

It helps when:

1 .You want to detect type-related error sooner in the development cycle. For example, this code may yield unexpected error if you omit the type:

```
isActive: any;
...
this.isActive = "false";
...
if (!this.isActive) {
  // this will not happen
}
```

2. You want to have better intellisense.

Comment: Thank you so much. Appreciated your effort.